# How to make a Counter?

Tags: java, oop, counter

I've got a OOP project, where I have to program the action of critters in a grid.

This is what I have now.

```
public class Frog implements Critter {
    //below is what letter represents the Frog in the grid.  Works fine.
    public char getChar() {
        return 'F';
    }

public int getMove(CritterInfo info) {
    //need to count the moves to determine how far to move
    int countF;
    countF++;
    int moveF2 = 0;
    if (countF % 3 == 1) {
        int moveF = (int)(Math.random() * 100);
        moveF2 = moveF;
        countF = 0;
    } 
    else {
        if (moveF2 < 25) {
            return NORTH;
        }
        else if (moveF2 < 50) {
            return SOUTH;
        } 
        else if (moveF2 < 75) {
            return EAST;
        }
        else {
            return WEST;
        }
    }
}
```

The Frog is supposed to pick a random direction, moves 3 in that direction, repeat.

I don't know how to make a counter to count the amount of moves.  I thought about:

```
public int getMove(CritterInfo info) {
    int countF = 0;
    countF++;
    int moveF2 = 0;
    if (countF % 3 == 1) {
        int moveF = (int)(Math.random() * 100);
        moveF2 = moveF;
        countF = 0;
    }
    else {
        ...(cut)
    }
 }
```

But the above obviously doesn't work because it resets countF to 0 every time it gets run.

Comment: `int countF; countF++;`? how does this work?

Comment: What is the `CritterInfo` ? When it is being initialized and can't you store the contF in that? and in getMove() you need to get the contF from the critter info and increment it.

Comment: There are so many things wrong I don't even know where to start...

Comment: I'm new to Java, be nice ;-;

Comment: CritterInfo is some part of the interface that we're supposed to use.
"The Critter interface defines the methods necessary for an animal
// to participate in the critter simulation.  It must return a
// character when getChar is called that is used for displaying it on
// the screen.  The getMove method must return a legal move (one of
// the constants NORTH, SOUTH, EAST, WEST, CENTER).
"

Comment: Okay, then you need to make it as an instance variable as the answers suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your *countF* variable is a local variable, thus every time the method is called it will be initialised as 0. You need to make it a field variable. If it's a field variable then it will belong to the object and not to the method. This means that it will only be initialised as 0 when the object is created.

```
int countF = 0;

public int getMove(CritterInfo info) {
    countF++;
    int moveF2 = 0;
    if (countF % 3 == 1) {
        int moveF = (int)(Math.random() * 100);
        moveF2 = moveF;
        countF = 0;
    } else {
    }
}
```

Comment: Still trying to figure it out.  Doesn't wanna compile because it keeps asking for me to return something, even though it should return it.  Didn't downvote anyone.

Comment: Worked for my other animal.  Thanks for the help!  Still gotta work on my Frog movement, but I think I can figure it out!

Answer (score 1):

If you move countF outside the function (as a member field instead of a local variable), wouldn't it do the trick ?
You seem like trying to force countF to 0, why ?

```
public class Frog implements Critter {
private int countF;

public Frog(){
countF = 0;
}

//below is what letter represents the Frog in the grid.  Works fine.
public char getChar() {
    return 'F';
}

public int getMove(CritterInfo info) {
    countF++;
    int moveF2 = 0;
    if (countF % 3 == 1) {
        int moveF = (int)(Math.random() * 100);
        moveF2 = moveF;
        countF = 0;
    } else {
          ....(cut)
    }
}
}
```